# xceed datagridcontrol for wpf - how to style inactiveselectionbackground property?

Tags: wpf, xceed-datagrid, xceed

I'm looking for a way to set the inactiveselectionbackground property either in xaml or in code for my datagridcontrol objects. I tried to set a style in xaml but couldn't find what I needed and I can't seem to find the property on the datagrid object itself in code. I was hoping somebody else fought this before and could show me what to do to work around it.

I'm using xceed datagridcontrol for wpf v4.3

The default behavior is to focus to the first row in the grid and not actually select it. So where I should expect a blue selected row color, I instead get the default systemcolors.inactivecaption value which is dark gray on some machines. I am trying to keep a consistent look despite the end user's OS.